# Modifying a simple jquery game

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify this game, right now it shows 9 images at random positions and the user has to click on them and when it reaches 10 clicks the game ends. I want to appear only one image. I will share the original function and the function I have modified it.

Original

```
function createImages(){
    var myarray= ["img/img1.gif","img/img2.gif","img/img3.png",
                "img/img4.gif","img/img5.gif","img/img6.gif",
                "img/img7.gif","img/img8.png", "img/img9.jpg"];
    var count=0;
    var div;
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        var randPos = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 500); 
        this.img = document.createElement("img");
        div = document.createElement("div");

        $("div").attr("id","div"+i);
        var randNew = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (5)); 
        var rand = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (9-count)); 
        this.img.src = myarray[rand];

        $('#div'+i).css("left", randPosition());
        $('#div'+i).css("right", randPosition());
        $('#div'+i).css("top", randPosition());
        $('#div'+i).css("bottom",randPosition());
        $('#div'+i).css("position","relative");
        $('#div'+i).show();
        div.appendChild(this.img);
        $("body").prepend(div);
        myarray.splice(rand,1);
        count++;
    }
}
```

After I modified it

```
function createImages(){
    var count=0;
    var div;
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        var randPos = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 500); 
        this.img = document.createElement("img");
        div = document.createElement("div");

        $("div").attr("id","div");
        var randNew = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (5)); 
        var rand = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (9-count)); 
        this.img.src = "img/img1.gif";

        $('#div').css("left", randPosition());
        $('#div').css("right", randPosition());
        $('#div').css("top", randPosition());
        $('#div').css("bottom",randPosition());
        $('#div').css("position","relative");
        $('#div').show();
        div.appendChild(this.img);
        $("body").prepend(div);
        count++;
    }
}
```

The problem is that now it appears the same image 10 times, I want it to appear only once and then disappear and appear again. Can anyone help me fix this issue.

If it's not to much to ask I would like to put this image inside a div so it wouldn't appear all over the page.

```
function randPosition() {
    return 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
}
```

Comment: can you show live demo with jsfiddle ?

Comment: what are the names of your images? can you iterate over them by index? 'img/img'+i+'.gif'

Comment: @LiamSchauerman yes I can iterate the images using a index, but I want to change this. I only want one image to appear once.

Comment: @Reza-S4 i tried to copy my code to jsfiddle but it shows nothing. I have never used this tool before. If it's of any help I can share all my code in here

Comment: what is the randPosition() ?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the function randPosition

Comment: In your code, you're quite obviously creating 10 images and inserting them all by wrapping them in a `<div>` and using `$('body').prepend(div)`. Please find out what your code does before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `createImages()` function you have a loop that adds the image 10 times:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   ...
}
```

Remove it, and it'll do it only once. Also you can simplify the code removing some random variables that are not used.

Further, this two sentences aren't correct. The first one creates a `div` in a variable named also `div`. The second is selector for all `div` elements, you are not referencing the new created one as I think you expect.

```
div = document.createElement("div");
$("div").attr("id","div");
```

You should create a jQuery object with the new created div to work with it:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");

$div = $(div);  // << Create jQuery object wrapping the new div
$div.css("left", randPosition());
```

Edited function:

```
function createImages(){
    var div = document.createElement("div");

    $div = $(div);
    $div.css("left", randPosition());
    $div.css("right", randPosition());
    $div.css("top", randPosition());
    $div.css("bottom",randPosition());
    $div.css("position","relative");
    $div.show();

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/25x25/4F4/000.png";

    div.appendChild(img);
    $("body").prepend(div);
}
```

EDIT: I've built a JSFiddle for you so you can play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/6aLh9qam/3/

Comment: This one is your first attempt (which generates 10 images) http://jsfiddle.net/6aLh9qam/1/

Comment: the code you provided is ok creates only one imege but is always in the top-left corner, and this image doesn't dissapear and appea again in some other place, check my complete code http://jsfiddle.net/6aLh9qam/2/

Comment: Oops, You are right. I just focused on the generation, not in the rest. Check this one, I'll edit my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/6aLh9qam/3/

Comment: Note that this function only creates one image at some random place. It doesn't handle user interaction, nor delete to create the next one. But I hope it helps you to start with it.